# How to check for email duplication from array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

Have two emails and trying to check if it matches anything in my data array which is an array of emails.

Thought the below would return `true` or `false` but it seems to be not working:

```
 const email1 = test.emailAddress.value;
 const email2 = test2.emailAddress.value;

 data.every(({ email }) => email.value === email1 || email.value === email2);
```

Comment: sounds like you need to use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some); The `some()` method tests whether **at least one element** in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function

Comment: You want to check if *every* item in the array matches `email1` or `email2`?

Comment: Whats the structure of `data`?

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter` your data with the matched array of two emails like so:

```js
const data = [
  {email: 'test@test.com'},
  {email: 'test1@test.com'},
  {email: 'test2@test.com'}
]

const email1 = 'test1@test.com'
const email2 = 'test2@test.com'

const matched = data.filter(({ email }) => [email1, email2].includes(email));
console.log(matched)
```

Comment: The problem is the email one is part of that data so I need to exclude that. bascially email1 will be the current emai that I'm checking and it will be already dynamically added to the data array. So it always returns a value. How would I get around that.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the `.every` method checks if every `email` in the `data` array is either `email1` or `email2`, if at least one of the emails in the `data` array fails the condition, the `.every` method returns false. Which means that the `.every` method is not suitable for what you want to achieve.

```
var exists = data.some(({email}) => [email1, email2].includes(email))
```

Thats with the assumption that `data` is a array of objects that contain email attribute. If data is simply an array of email strings, then it should be

```
var exists = data.some(email => [email1, email2].includes(email))
```

Comment: Don't do `.filter(…).length > 0`. There's a much more efficient specific method for this.

Comment: Please give reasons @Bergi.

Comment: @Bergi, I will really love to know about the efficient method.

Comment: It's `.some` - it works like `.every` but returns as soon as it finds at least one match. A `.filter` will go through THE ENTIRE array, then construct AN ENTIRE NEW array for you to only check if the result has at least one match (what `.some` does) and then the result is discarded.

Answer (score -2):

Unless you provide your `data` it is hard to figure out what is going on. But you can use`includes` to check if an element is present in an array or not.

> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.

```
if( data.includes(email1) || data.includes(email2)){ // ||  && depending upon your needs
   //do something
}
```